# Tweepy Stream python, running error on IDLE

Tags: python, twitter, stream, python-idle, tweepy

When I run my script just a blank shell opens and nothing happens. It gives a restart line in the output shell and stops. Then when i try to cancel the window it asks me, "The program is still running, do you want to kill it".. I waited for over 15 mins but nothing happened. Can you help me. I am using Mac

Here is my code

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)`enter code here`

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

Comment: Tried your code with no problem. Used `idle` and  `Mac`. Only I had to remove your `enter code here`, which I guess is just a typo. It must be something related to your machine/installation. I'd suggest you add debugging lines to get a clue on what's happening. With the information you give now, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: What happens if you run your file, minus the SyntaxError in on_error, directly with Python in a console window.  If it works the same, then Idle is not part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in the code snippet you provided The first one is in the `on_error` method which I think is **not** causing any problems since this method would be invoked only when an error is encountered, still you can rewrite the method as:

```
def on_error(self, status):
    print ("The error is : "+status)
```

And the next issue is in the line `twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])`, By using this line the performance of this code now depends upon as how many public tweets contain the keyword `car` in their tweets , if unfortunately None of public tweets have been made using this keyword then you will get nothing printed on the console, So I will recommend you to use more set of keywords like: `vehicle, automobile, etc` to increase you chance.

For testing purpose you could remove this line from the piece of code and end you code at `twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())` , If you still see no output on the IDLE console then you should try some other text editor like `sublime, Canopy, etc.`.